# Install Windows 10 apps using a .bat script?

Tags: windows, powershell, appx, appxmanifest

When I try this (it installs window store, calculator, photos and sticky notes using a **.bat file**) :

```
Powershell "Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers *WindowsStore*  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
Powershell "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *windowscalculator* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}"
Powershell "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.Windows.Photos | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
Powershell "Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
```

Powershell returns me an error: `Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument « \AppXManifest.xml »`

I also tried that:

```
Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *windowscalculator* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.Windows.Photos | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
```

it returns: `'get-appxpackage' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I tried the above one in a **Powershell script (.ps1)** and it works perfectly.

The thing is that I would like to implement this code into an existing .bat script. I can't just convert my .bat into .ps1 because I need to re-write it in powershell and I do not have the skills at all.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create a Powershell script and start it over the bat script.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\SE\Desktop\ps.ps1
```

you would have then the ability to change freely what it should install over the Powershell script and wouldn't have to make major changes in the bat script.

Comment: It works but it's a little bit annoying. I'll look for something more convienent but i'll go this way if i find nothing. Thanks